# for loop not working as expected -grabbing undefined?

Tags: javascript, json

Here is an example of what I'm running into. because person.job and person.alterego are sometimes flipped when looping through this I get undefined if those are in [1] rather than [0].  So I'm not sure how to get it to ignore if person[0].job doesn't exist and instead grab data from person[1].job.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <style>
        th {
            color: #fff;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr class="bg-info">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Job</th>
            <th>alterEgo</th>
        </tr>

        <tbody id="myTable">

        </tbody>
    </table>




    <script>
        const data = {
            "person": {
                "Clark": [{
                    "lastName": "Kent",
                    "job": "Reporter",
                    "roll": "20"
                }, {
                    "alterEgo": "Superman",
                    "powers": ["strength", "lasereyes", "hair"]
                }],
                "Bruce": [{
                    "lastName": "Wayne",
                    "job": "Playboy",
                    "roll": "30"
                }, {
                    "alterEgo": "Batman",
                    "powers": ["fighting", "gadgets", "money"]
                }],
                "Peter": [{
                    "alterEgo": "Spider-man",
                    "powers": ["strength", "arm-goo", "wit"]
                }, {
                    "lastName": "Parker",
                    "job": "Photographer",
                    "roll": "40"
                }]
            }
        }



        buildTable(data)


        function buildTable(data2) {



            var table = document.getElementById('myTable')
            for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {}
            Object.entries(data2.person).forEach(([name, details]) => {
                console.log("this one", name, details[i].job, details[i].alterEgo)
                console.log("length?", i)
                console.log("data2", data2)

                var row = `<tr>
              <td>${name}</td>
              <td>${details[i].job}</td>
              <td>${details[i].alterEgo}</td>

            </tr>`
                table.innerHTML += row

            });
            // }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I expected the for var i++ to keep populating until it found a value?

Comment: Maybe you can just ditch the `i` attempt altogether and just do something like `details[0].job || details[1].job`?  That way if the first element doesn't have a `job` property then it'll use the one on the second element.  [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7usxkghq/)  (Though honestly, if you can correct the data structure then that would be the ideal approach.  "Smart data structures and dumb code works a lot better than the other way around." -Eric S. Raymond)

Comment: name is person.name. so the table populates with Clark, Bruce, Peter just fine but the job only populates for clark and bruce and alterego only for peter.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what your for loop is even doing there (it does nothing)

Your details arrays seem to be in random order, in other words, the job can be in the first or second object in the array

Given that, you'll need to check for `job` and `alterEgo` in both elements of that `details` array

Something like the following works

```js
const data = {
  "person": {
    "Clark": [{
      "lastName": "Kent",
      "job": "Reporter",
      "roll": "20"
    }, {
      "alterEgo": "Superman",
      "powers": ["strength", "lasereyes", "hair"]
    }],
    "Bruce": [{
      "lastName": "Wayne",
      "job": "Playboy",
      "roll": "30"
    }, {
      "alterEgo": "Batman",
      "powers": ["fighting", "gadgets", "money"]
    }],
    "Peter": [{
      "alterEgo": "Spider-man",
      "powers": ["strength", "arm-goo", "wit"]
    }, {
      "lastName": "Parker",
      "job": "Photographer",
      "roll": "40"
    }]
  }
};

buildTable(data);
function buildTable(data2) {
    const table = document.getElementById('myTable');
    const html = Object.entries(data2.person).map(([name, details]) => {
        // combine all the objects in the details array, and "extract" job and alterEgo using destructing assignment
        const {job, alterEgo} = Object.fromEntries(details.flatMap(Object.entries));
        // this could be simplified to
        // const {job, alterEgo} = { ...details[0], ...details[1] };
        // if you KNOW that details has at most two objects in it
        
        return `<tr>
              <td>${name}</td>
              <td>${job}</td>
              <td>${alterEgo}</td>
            </tr>`
    });
    table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', html.join(''))
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr class="bg-info">
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Job</th>
    <th>alterEgo</th>
  </tr>

  <tbody id="myTable">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

I've made a couple of changes ... the html is built up as an array using `.map` ... once it's created, it is added to the table using the faster `insertAdjacentHTML` ... you can look that up on MDN documentation